# How to fix a funky roof transition

Tags: framing, roof

I'm getting ready to have my roof replaced and trying to tick off a few odd fixes before that.  One thing that has always bugged/puzzled me is the way this roof transition is framed. The roof on the left is the garage.  The roof on the right is a bedroom.  Both were clearly additions, though I'm not sure which came first (perhaps the bedroom?)  They framed it in a very strange way where the rafters from the addition penetrate the roof of the garage.  This creates a weird valley with rafters poking through into the garage.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?  It seems like a possible leak point, though I haven't had any issues yet. Previous roofer obviously just slapped a bunch of tar on it.  Can my roofer fix this (without making it worse)?  Or is it maybe not worth the effort if it hasn't been an issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't leak if the junction was flashed (and ideally sloped) properly under the shingles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After determining that there was indeed a fair amount of rot due to water intrusion around the penetration, I decided to tear it apart and do it right.  I'm not totally finished yet, but in essence I re-framed it so that the garage eave is correct.  The rake board coming from above (the right side in the first photo) needs to stop a couple inches short so that shingles can tuck up under.  Then, a [flashing detail](https://youtu.be/bck9kc04I4E?si=KqfjgUyxyXP_Bsvk) will cover the rake board so it stays dry.

This shows the completed repair from the outside w/ new roof deck to replace rotted.  The new rake board isn't attached yet, I'll wait until the roofers tear everything off so I can nail it from above.
[image]

This is the rafter scab from the inside:
[image]

I'll post a couple more photos when it's totally done but this gives the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not leaking, leave it alone!

You could cut those short rafter tails in the 2nd pic (the ones that penetrate the other roof), but then you're cutting that roof's support and it will end up slowly collapsing until you do have a leak and then a roof failure.

I would hope that the previous roofer did more than "slap a bunch of tar on it". Proper valley installation includes some sort of flashing. It could either be roll aluminum or a newer, "high tech" self adhesive type of membrane. (Note: "newer" as of the 1980s-90s time frame. Self-adhesive membranes aren't really that new, but in the history of roofs, they're a recent addition.)

Over that, proper shingle installation with a judicious application of roofing tar as appropriate should ensure a leak-proof installation for more than a decade (asphalt shingles usually come with 15-25 year warranties, you should expect the roof to be good for roughly that period if it's installed correctly).

Comment: Mostly I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to fix the appearance on the exterior (pics 1 & 2).  The two rafters that meet at an "X" create this bizarre little return/alcove that just doesn't seem correct, the right side of which is sagging because it doesn't have any support.

Comment: You'll need to add extra pics to your question, @icurays1. _I_ don't see any issues on the exterior shots that need to be fixed. Not saying they aren't there, just that I'm not seeing them. Also, you only seemed to have asked about the rafters poking through, not about an exterior issue. Advice still stands, though. If it's not leaking there's nothing to fix. If you're putting a new roof on, discuss the valley flashing with the contract to find out how they'll treat it, if you're satisfied with it, let it roll.